# OR operator inside a Where Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So inside a Where Active Record(AR) query you can do:

```
game_stickers.where('stickers.name != ?', 'Ban')
```

But how can you test matches against multiple strings with an OR operator **without** doing something like:

```
game_stickers.where('stickers.name != ? OR stickers.name != ?', 'Ban', 'Closed')
```

or **without** reverting to something like [see note below]:

```
game_stickers.where.not(stickers.name: ['Ban','Closed','Block'])
```

NOTE:

The reason I do not want to go with the last alternative is because I'm using some `joins` and `references` in my queries that (as far as I can see) do not play nicely with this option. The context code goes something like:

```
game_stickers_and_stickers = game_stickers.includes(:sticker)
game_stickers_and_stickers.where('stickers.name = ?', 'Ban').references(:stickers).where(placement_side: side)
```

Maybe a you can advise on the optimal way to do this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: it seems to me you want an AND between those conditions, not an OR. Think about it. Anyway, try this one

```
game_stickers_and_stickers = game_stickers.includes(:sticker)
game_stickers_and_stickers.where.not(stickers: {name: ['Ban','Closed','Block']}).where(placement_side: side)
```

that condition fragment should be converted to the SQL

```
WHERE stickers.name NOT IN ('Ban', 'Closed', 'Block')
```